# Top level sleep function for Javascript

Tags: javascript, sleep

I need a sleep function for my Js code. I can use a promise based function but that needs `await` keyword to work. But the problem is I need to use the sleep function at the top level.

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}

await sleep(5) //invalid
```

So I can't write `await sleep(5)` because Js do not support it.

How to implement a function that will work like,

```js
let i = 10;
while (i > 0) {
    console.log("sleeping..." + i);
    sleep(1);
    i--;
}

console.log("Hello");

sleep(5);

console.log("World");
```

Is there any way?

Comment: You can't `await` unless you're inside an `async` function. Consider `(async function() { ... })()` and wrap all your code in that.

Comment: You either need to put everything in a function, or you need to switch to ESM which _does_ support top-level await.

Comment: you could use an iife

Comment: ideally you shouldn't sleep

Comment: Using nodejs for it. Also browser.

Comment: @CastlerSteve if you're using Nodejs the easiest thing you can do is rename your file to end with `.mjs`

Comment: I'm building a linear interpreter. So I cannot use any nesting.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Though it's crazy and not recomanded but Yes you can implement that with `Date.now()` function.

```js
function sleep(seconds) {
    const start = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - start < seconds * 1000) {}
}
```

This function compares the current time with the starting time using your defined time.
As we know `while loop` like this will block the main thread and the next lines are not executed until it releases the thread.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's going to block and brutalize your CPU while it's waiting.

Comment: Yes, there is no other way. He wanted that anyways :(

Answer (score 0):

Top-level await is supported in Ecmascript Modules. Since you're using the Node.js, the easiest way to switch is to rename your `.js` file to `.mjs`.

If you can't do that, your only other option is wrapping your code in a function.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any way to do it without a level of wrapping, if you cannot use top level awaits.

You can use `.then`

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

sleep(2000).then(() => {
  //Sadly all your logic will reside inside this block
});
```

Another way to do this is using an IIFE.

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}

(async () => {
  await sleep(3000);
  //Sadly all your logic will reside inside this block

})();
```

Comment: function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}

(async () => {
  await sleep(3000);
  //Sadly all your logic will reside inside this block

})();

sleep(3000);

console.log('hi')

Here hi runs immediately.

Comment: I think i should be more clear. ALl your logic will be inside the `{}`. That is the problem. Edited answer to be more clear

Comment: I need the thing work in top level. @Fuad Hasan's answer works the way I want.